# Async.eachSeries on FindOne doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I have a problem with async for a FindOne. I have an array of id called idChildren (like [ [516152], [158796], [123654, 147852] ]) and I want to check if the id of the current position on the array is on the database. children is an array where I save the string with all informations.

```
for (var j = 0; j < idChildren.length; j++)
{
    async.eachSeries(idChildren, function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < idChildren[j].length; i++)
        {
            Children.findOne({ _id: idChildren[j] }, function (err, child) {
                console.log("I'm in the findOne");
                if (child != undefined && !err) {
                    if (child.lastname == undefined)
                        tmp2 += ',';
                    else
                        tmp2 += child.lastname + ',';
                    if (child.firstname == undefined)
                        tmp2 += ',';
                    else
                        tmp2 += child.firstname + ',';
                    if (child.birthday == undefined)
                        tmp2 += ',';
                    else
                        tmp2 += child.birthday + ',';
                    tmp2 += '\n';
                }
                children.push(tmp2);
                tmp2 = "";
          });
        }
    });
}
console.log(children);
```

The problem is "console.log(children)" print [ , , ] and just after "I'm in the findOne" three times. I think it's that my async.eachSeries is not correct.
Can you help me ?

**EDIT**

```
async.eachSeries(idChildren, function(idChild, next) {
    Children.findOne({ _id: idChild }, function (err, child) {
        console.log("I'm in the findOne");
        if (child != undefined && !err) {
            if (child.lastname == undefined)
                tmp2 += ',';
            else
                tmp2 += child.lastname + ',';
            if (child.firstname == undefined)
                tmp2 += ',';
            else
                tmp2 += child.firstname + ',';
            if (child.birthday == undefined)
                tmp2 += ',';
            else
                tmp2 += child.birthday + ',';
            tmp2 += '\n';
        }
        children.push(tmp2);
        tmp2 = "";
        next();
        return;
  });
});

console.log(children);
```

The output is :

> [] 
>   I'm in the findOne 
>   I'm in the findOne 
>   I'm in the findOne 
>   I'm in the findOne 
>   I'm in the findOne

So the console.log(children) is executed first and just after the FindOne loops works.
If you console.log(children) at the end of the findOne, the array is correct.

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, the code works properly and the problem is only at the timing of the console.log() and any other logics you want to perform at the end of the loop.

If this the case, use the following code:

```
async.eachSeries(idChildren, function(idChild, next) {
    Children.findOne({ _id: idChild }, function (err, child) {
        console.log("I'm in the findOne");
        if (child != undefined && !err) {
            if (child.lastname == undefined)
                tmp2 += ',';
            else
                tmp2 += child.lastname + ',';
            if (child.firstname == undefined)
                tmp2 += ',';
            else
                tmp2 += child.firstname + ',';
            if (child.birthday == undefined)
                tmp2 += ',';
            else
                tmp2 += child.birthday + ',';
            tmp2 += '\n';
        }
        children.push(tmp2);
        tmp2 = "";
        next();
        return;
  });
},
// finally method
function(err) {
    if (err) {
        //do some error handling
    }

    console.log(children);
    // do some other logics
});
```

As you can see, the async.eachSeries method accepts another function parameter which stands for the "finally method" - the method that will get called after the loop is done.

If one of the loop iterations will call next with a parameter that will stand for an error - like:

```
return next("Cannot find child object");
```

In that case - the loop will stop running and the "err" parameter in the finally method will contain the string you passed as error.

If there were no errors, the "err" will be null and you can continue performing whatever logics you desire.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, my web console prints :
04:27:45 web.1   |  []
04:27:45 web.1   |  I'm in the findOne
04:27:45 web.1   |  I'm in the findOne
04:27:46 web.1   |  I'm in the findOne
04:27:46 web.1   |  I'm in the findOne
04:27:46 web.1   |  I'm in the findOne

So children is print first and just after I'm in the async.EachSeries so my children variable is always empty :/

Comment: Please attach your entire code with the changes and what is printed as an edit to the question so I can understand what exactly is the problem.